# python: executing "start /wait someprocess"

Tags: python, winapi, subprocess

I've used Python's `subprocess.call()` before, but how do you get it to act like the Windows `START /WAIT myprogram`?

I've tried `subprocess.call(['start', '/wait', 'myprogram.exe'])` but it can't find `start` and neither can I.

Comment: What does that do in Windows? Is subprocess.popen what you are looking for?

Comment: I have a program that's a non-console app, so I need to explicitly wait for it to finish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to wait for a spawned process, then use `subprocess.Popen` and then either `wait` or `communicate`. `start` is AFAIR a shell construct, not a real exec (so you'd have to use `shell = True` — but that still wouldn't do what you want).